# Absolute scale for color map?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a plot with an intensity that varies over time:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-30:.1:30);
figure;
colormap(bone);


for t = 0:0.1:2*pi
    R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
    Z = cos(t)*abs(besselj(2,R));
    surf(Z,'EdgeColor','None');
    view(90,90);
    axis([0 600 0 600 -0.5 0.5])
    pause(0.1);
end
```

I want to look at this from the top, such that as the Z value changes, the color changes. The problem is that rather than having an absolute scale (black = -0.5, white = 0.5), the color scale is relative to the maximum and minimum values, such that the colors only change when the sign flips change. How can I set an absolute scale for the color map?

Thank you.

Comment: No, I want to have a gradient. So, it moves from black to white as the value increases. But I want the maximum and minimum values to be fixed. The way it is set up right now, I can see no color change as the intensity decreases. I want to say "at -5, black. At 5, white. In between, a gradient."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `scaled` colour mapping mode and set the limits of the scaling by using the [`caxis`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) command.

Now the problem with your current code is that you call `surf` at each iteration of the loop, essentially destroying the current plot and generating a new plot each time. This will reset a lot of properties, including the `caxis` limits to auto. To overcome that, simply create your plot only once before the loop, then in the loop you only change the properties which are modified (the `Z` values in this case). This way everything else stays the same in the figure.

So you code becomes:

```
%% // Prepare and initialize the surface plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-30:.1:30);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) ;         %// this doesn't need to be in the loop

Z = cos(0)*abs(besselj(2,R)) ;                  %// calculate initial value to create the surface
surfHandle = surf( Z , 'EdgeColor','None' ) ;   %// create a first surface, and save the handle to the surface object
colormap(bone);
colorbar                        %// this is optional, just to make sure the colorbar does not vary
caxis([-5 5 ] ) ;               %// this is what sets the color scaling to what you want
view(90,90);
axis([0 600 0 600 -0.5 0.5]) ;  %// this doesn't need to be in the loop anymore

%% // Modify and update the surface plot
for t = 0:pi/100:2*pi
    Z = cos(t)*abs(besselj(2,R));
    set( surfHandle , 'ZData' , Z )
    drawnow
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Read [coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html#f0-20897) for more info on how surfaces can be colored.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want white for values less than 0 and black for values greater than 0, you ca simply do:

```
surf(Z,sign(Z),'EdgeColor','None');
```

which uses the optional `C` argument to `surf`, telling Matlab to colour the plot depending on the values of `C`, not `Z`. `sign(Z)` is a matrix that has 1's where `Z>0`, 0's where `Z=0`, and -1's where `Z<0`.